# I don't know why but the 2nd for loop for printing the id's is not working properly and a sometimes if I give length 9 to 3rd employee program exits

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *ptr;
    int n;
    printf("This program was created to store Employee's ID data.\nIt can take both alphabet as well as integers as id.\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("\nFor Employee No: %d",i);
        printf("\nEnter the size(in number) of your id:");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        ptr=(char*)malloc(n*sizeof(char));
        printf("Enter your id:");
        scanf("%s",&ptr[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("The id of employee number %d is %s\n",i,ptr[i]);
    }
    
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm new to this stuff as I've just learned the the four functions of dynamic memory allocation and tried to make this simple code. But for some reason I don't know why the program is not running as I wish for it to work. 
I want the program to get the id of 3 employee. The program will first ask them to choose length of the id's and then get their id's and store them in a variable. The id's should be able to contain both characters as well as integers. After storing them it should print them.
But the second for loop never prints and the program apparently stops and exits. Please guide me.

Comment: Please output and report the return value of each of your scanf calls in the failure case. You are ignoring them at your own peril.

Comment: You store the string in ptr[i] but the space you allocated is in ptr.

Comment: @stark No, only characters, not strings, are stored in `ptr[i]`.

Comment: Thanks @Yunnosch,@stark,@MikeCat for guiding me. I didn't really think it through . Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to read 3 IDs, so you should allocate a 3-element array of `char*`.
- You should allocate (at least) one more element than the length of ID to store terminating null-character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *ptr[3]; /* allocate an array of char* */
    int n;
    printf("This program was created to store Employee's ID data.\nIt can take both alphabet as well as integers as id.\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("\nFor Employee No: %d",i);
        printf("\nEnter the size(in number) of your id:");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        ptr[i]=(char*)malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char)); /* allocate one more element for terminating null-character and save it to an element of the array */
        printf("Enter your id:");
        scanf("%s",ptr[i]); /* remove an extra & and pass char* for scanf() */
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("The id of employee number %d is %s\n",i,ptr[i]);
    }
    
    /* free each elements */
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        free(ptr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Your code will be better if you check the results of `malloc()` and `scanf()`.